# Disposing implicit references within using statements

Tags: c#

When "nesting" `using` statements/blocks, such as a `StreamWriter` within a `FileStream`

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create))
{
    using (var fsw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Would the `FileStream` be properly disposed of if it's reference is implicit?** If not, would `FileStream` dispose of it when it itself is disposed of?

```
    using (var fsw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.Create)) )
    {
        ...
    }
```

**Also, does the following "stacked" `using` statements generate differently than the first example that is "nested" (are the try/catch blocks nested or not depending on the syntax)?**

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create))    
using (var fsw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please only ask one question per posted question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would the FileStream be properly disposed of if it's reference is implicit? Will FileStream dispose of it when it itself is disposed of?

The question is nonsensical. I believe the question you intended to ask is:

> If the `StreamWriter` (or reader) is disposed (or closed), will it automatically dispose the underlying `Stream`?

Yes. For future reference, consider reading the documentation; your question is clearly answered there.

Now, you might reason as follows:  suppose a thread abort exception is thrown after the creation of the stream but before the creation of the writer or reader. In the two-usings case, the stream is disposed; in the one-using case, it is not. Therefore the two-using case is both different and better.

That reasoning is specious. Suppose a thread abort exception is thrown after the handle for the stream is allocated but before the file stream variable is assigned; even in the two-usings case, the stream is not disposed.

The moral of the story is: you must not rely upon `using` to dispose of critical resources in a world with thread abort exceptions. `using` is for politeness; it is not a guarantee that a resource will be deallocated.

> does the following "stacked" using statements generate differently than the first example that is "nested"?

Please only ask one question per question.

The question is unclear. Is your question whether the two forms are *exactly semantically equivalent*, or whether they generate *exactly the same IL*?  Those questions have opposite answer. Yes, they are semantically equivalent, and no, they do not necessarily generate the same IL if optimizations are turned off.

In general,

```
statement
```

and

```
{
  statement
}
```

are semantically equivalent. (Though note that a *declaration statement* is syntactically illegal in some contexts where a statement block is not. And of course, braces introduce a declaration space.)

However the C# compiler may choose to generate extra nop instructions so that the debugger has some place to put breakpoints associated with the braces. Thus, the code generated is not identical.  Generating extra nops can cause knock-on effects on branch locations, and therefore branch offset sizes, and therefore branch instruction sizes, and therefore branch instruction opcodes, for instance.

Comment: I adjusted my first question to "Would the FileStream be properly disposed of if it's reference is implicit? *If not*, would FileStream dispose of it when it itself is disposed of?"

Comment: *"Suppose a thread abort exception is thrown after the handle for the stream is allocated but before the file stream variable is assigned"* - **This situation can't happen in a `try` block?** *"you must not rely upon `using` to dispose of critical resources in a world with thread abort exceptions"* - **What is the alternative?**

Comment: @samusarin: Of course the situation can happen in a try block; a using *is* a try block. There is no alternative. **You must not rely upon using to dispose of critical resources in a word with thread abort exceptions**.  Are you relying on that for the correctness of your program? Because if you are, *stop doing that*. Structure your program so that critical resources do not need to be disposed in a timely manner, or don't ever abort a thread.

Comment: Would it be feasible for the runtime to have `using` statements execute their resulting `try` blocks atomically. This way when a thread's `finally` blocks are called during a `ThreadAbortException`, resources will be properly disposed and left in a consistent state. I mean, it already has it's own syntax, so giving it it's own semantics (from `try`) shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @samusarin: Sure, that's feasible; it's just insufficient. Now solve the same problem for out of memory exceptions.

Comment: @samusarin: If you go down this road, you'll find that you are re-inventing Constrained Execution Regions, a CLR feature that almost no one understands. Is it feasible to have a region of code which is uninterruptible and nothing bad can happen?  **yes**.  The fact that you've never heard of this feature before just now indicates how rare it is that someone actually needs to solve that problem, and how difficult it is to solve. **It is easier to simply structure your programs so that disposers are not required to be called in a timely manner.**

Answer (score 1):

> Would the FileStream be properly disposed of if it's reference made
>   implicit?

Yes. The var keyword gets determined at compile time and it would result in the same code and be disposed of correctly.

> Also, does the following generate differently than the first example
>   that is nested (are the try/catch blocks nested or not depending on
>   the syntax)?

There is no catch block with the using statement. The using statement is the equivalent of try finally. Depending on the compiler optimizations, the original code may result in the same as the stacked using statement. Logically, it really shouldn't matter.

Comment: Updated the explanation, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Yeah, thanks.... Well, the logic *would* matter if it effected performance.

Comment: Is ILDASM.EXE the tool that should be used when inspecting compiler generation? Is there another tool to view the "substituted", or "pre-processed" source before compilation and IL assembly to see what it's doing?

Comment: Yes, you can use ILDASM to inspect the dlls. Can you elaborate on why performance would be affected?

Comment: I guess `ICompileModule` and `CSharpCompilation` are useful for this as well... I was told (and read) that there is a significant performance hit when an exception occurs, so it would seem like nesting `try` blocks would only compound the matter. For a "fatal" or "halting" exception I suppose it wouldn't matter, however for a "non-fatal" exception repeatedly occurring in a tight loop (say when reading a bunch of invalid DB data) things could get noticeably slow.

Comment: You are correct in that if you have bunch of nested try/catch blocks and are re-throwing exceptions, performance would be horrible. However, the using clause shouldn't affect exception performance since there is no catch block.

Comment: @samusarin: If your performance is gated on the behaviour of cleanup logic in `using` statements then *you must have an extremely unusual program*. The supposition of your argument is that *opening and closing a file is an insignificant cost compared to the additional few nanoseconds of overhead cost of the `try-finally` that ensures the close*. That is an *extraordinary* claim. Opening a file often results in **spinning a metal plate**.  Do you have any evidence whatsoever that your performance is gated on *try overhead*?

Comment: @EricLippert My apologies, was considering `try/catch` in general, even though opening `File`s with `using` is what's being discussed.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to .NET 4.5 the `StreamWriter` class assumed it owned the stream that was passed into it. So the below will close and dispose of the `FileStream` when the `StreamWriter` is closed/disposed.

```
using (var fsw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.Create)) )
{
    ...
}
```

As of .NET 4.5 there is a [`StreamWriter` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712853(v=vs.110).aspx) with a Boolean parameter that, when True, will leave the `FileStream` open.

So you have control over whether the `FileStream` is disposed or not.

---

As for stacking the `using` statements: the `{ }`'s are optional when containing a single statement, just as they are for `if`, `for` and so on.  Stacking the `using`'s is a formatting convenience for those who view the indention to be excessive and unnecessary.

I would suggest following the same convention you would for other block statements when they contain a single statement to keep your code consistent.

Comment: I prefer the *nested* syntax for the same reasons you gave, consistency and clarity. However, if they result in nested `try {}` blocks then (from my understanding) I would try to avoid and use the *stacked* syntax.

Comment: @samusarin: If you have nested `using`s then you have nested `try`s regardless of whether the body of the `using` is a block statement or a `using` statement.  Why do you feel it is necessary or desirable to avoid nested `try`s? You seem to have some idea that braces are special. Braces are just a way to combine zero or more statements into one statement, and define a declaration space for locals.